# Mixing C++ instance methods with C callback functions

Tags: c++

### problem

I have the following C callback signature from a C library called `Foo`:

```c
void (* RequestCallbackFunc)(int)
```

This library also provides a utility function for registering said callback.

```c
extern void SetRequestCallback(RequestallbackFunc request_cbf);
```

I have a C++ class `App` with a instance method `HandleRequest`. What's the correct way to have `HandleRequest` called when `request_cbf` is called?

### my naive solution

#### App.hpp

```c
#include <Foo.h> // include my C library

#include <Bar.hpp>

class App {
    public:
        App();
        ~App();

        void HandleRequest(int x);
    public:
        Bar * bar_; // raw pointer for demonstration purposes
}
```

#### App.cpp

```c
#include "App.hpp"

extern "C" {
    static void handle_request(int x);
}

static void handle_request(int x) {
    static std::auto_ptr<App> my_app( new App() );
    my_app->HandleRequest(x);
}

App::App() {
    SetRequestCallback( handle_request );
    bar_ = new Bar();
}

App::~App() {
    delete bar_;
}

void App::HandleRequest(int x) {
    bar_->DoSomething( x );
    // more 'work'...
}
```

Am I approaching this problem the correct way? Are there additional ways to interface C++ with C callbacks?

Comment: There is no simple solution for compatibility with C style callbacks when using member functions. The [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2) outlines the common methods.

Comment: Is this real code? Do you really have a callback with one integer parameter? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Please note that in your code, the `A` that registers the callback is not the `A` that receives callbacks.

Comment: This will not compile: "static std::auto_ptr<App> A( new A() );", because there is no "A" type. At least run your code through compiler before asking questions.

Comment: @SigTerm Apologies. "A" is simply an instance of App. I've changed it to "my_app".

Comment: @n.m No. The function also takes a "void*" which is a handle to a context within the library. The library code does some funky stuff with this pointer, so I can't use it for custom data unless I edit the library code.

Comment: @Ben Voigt This was my fear. Thank you.

Comment: @Ncarlson: Does the library allow you to store any pointer of your own with the context, then get it later?  If yes, use that feature to store an `App*`.

Comment: A library that doesn't let you pass your data to your function is stuck in the 1980s (hello qsort). Just an observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why use pointers?

```
static void handle_request(int x) {
    static A instance;
    instance.HandleRequest(x);
}
```

(Same goes for `Bar`), though to be honest, you may as well call the method in `Bar` directly (unless the redirection through `A` is required)

Alternatively, rather than a free function, pass in a pointer to a static function in `A` matching the same signature - inside this you can access the single instance of `A` to use...

btw. some apis use a pattern where during registration you can pass in a pointer to some user data, which is passed in the callback, this could be for example a pointer to an instance of `A` to handle the callback - this way you can avoid all the singleton business...

Comment: The full signature is void (* RequestCallbackFunc)(LIBOBJ, int). Within the library code, the LIBOBJ parameter gets cast to a type called "_LIBOBJ". This struct, indeed, has a member "void* userPointer". Well, I learned something today.

Comment: @Ncarlson: so you can use the "void* userPointer" to store your class instance's "this" pointer and forward the call to your App::HandleRequest() method.

Answer (score 3):

What is the purpose of that `int` parameter in the callback?

Well designed C interface APIs usually provide a way to pass a "status" parameter to the C function callback (which can be used to pass some information like the C++ class instance `this` pointer), like [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s `LPVOID lpParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create another class which can be accessed statically and which registers different objects to manage the callback. The object to use can be determined by the x parameter (or if not necessary, you can register a single handler).

```
// Pseudocode
class Middleman {
    // map to select the handler object
    std::map<int, App> handlersMap_;

public:

    registerNewHandler(int x, const App& a) {
        // add new entry to the map
        [...]
    }

    static std::map<int, App> getHandlersMap() {
        return handlersMap_;
    }
}
```

Managing the callback:

```
static void handle_request(int x) {
    Middleman::getHandlersMap[x].HandleRequest(x);
}
```

With this design you have great flexibility.
The map of the Middleman could be replaced by a single handler, which is registered using the same registerNewHandler method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the cify trick and try to offer a lambda object to C, still, you need to be careful:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79612/c-ifying-a-capturing-lambda

Answer (score -2):

```
static void handle_request(int x) {
    static std::auto_ptr<App> A( new A() );
    A->HandleRequest(x);
}
```

This is a kind of a singleton. Since it is an anti-pattern, therefore it is bad.

I would create a function, and a global variable or type App. Something like this :

```
//App.hpp
#include <Foo.h> // include my C library

#include <Bar.hpp>

class App {
    public:
        App();
        ~App();

        void HandleRequest(int x);
    public:
        Bar * bar_; // raw pointer for demonstration purposes
}

extern App app;
void HandlerRequest(int x);
```

Then the implementation :

```
//App.cpp
#include "App.hpp"

App::App() : bar(new Bar) {
    SetRequestCallback( handle_request );
}

App::~App() {
    delete bar_;
}

void App::HandleRequest(int x) {
    bar_->DoSomething( x );
    // more 'work'...
}
App app;
void HandlerRequest(int x)
{
  app.HandlerRequest(x);
}
```

Comment: what? a "global variable" rather than a singleton (erm, difference being?;)

Comment: @Nim Singleton is hidden instance of a global variable, therefore stupid.

Comment: I consider singletons bad because they are effectively globals. What you do, is what I consider bad without calling it a pattern.

Comment: @pmr No, I call it by the name : global variable. There are no needs for singletons