# How to use C++ Function Pointer as Parameter to a C Funcion Pointer/Callback

Tags: c++, c, callback, function-pointers

I do know about C++ lambdas or C function pointers, but I don't know how to mix them together. I already found [Mixing C++ instance methods with C callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901882/mixing-c-instance-methods-with-c-callback-functions) , but it does not relies to my needs.

I have a C++ class the include C headers, like these:

```
extern "C" {
#include <jack/jack.h>
#include <jack/types.h`enter code here`>
#include <jack/ringbuffer.h>
#include <jack/midiport.h>
}
#include <QDialog>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include "Cliente.h"

class FormQStudio : public QDialog
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FormQStudio(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~FormQStudio();

    void playMIDIFile(QString file) noexcept(false);

    int theCallback(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg);
};
```

The C headers defines some types :

```
typedef uint32_t         jack_nframes_t;
typedef int  (*JackProcessCallback)(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg);

int jack_set_process_callback (jack_client_t *client,
                   JackProcessCallback process_callback,
                   void *arg) JACK_OPTIONAL_WEAK_EXPORT;
```

The implementaion of my C++ class needs to pass `theCallback(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)` as a parameter to C function `jack_set_process_callback`. But I don't know how to do it.

```
#include "FormQStudio.h"
FormQStudio::FormQStudio(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FormQStudio)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void FormQStudio::playMIDIFile(QString file) noexcept(false){
    smf_t *smf = smf_load(file.toUtf8());
    smf_event_t *event;

    Cliente *c = new Cliente("QStudio");
    c->inicializarCliente( 
       /* HOW TO REFERENCE this->processJackCallback as a parameter? */
   );

}
};
```

The class "Cliente" is this:

```
extern "C" {
#include <jack/jack.h>
#include <jack/types.h>
#include <jack/ringbuffer.h>
#include <jack/midiport.h>
}

#include <QString>
#include <QMap>

#include "ClientePorta.h"
#include "QStageException.h"

class Cliente
{
public:
    Cliente(QString clientName);

    struct MidiMessage {
        jack_nframes_t  time;
        int     len;    /* Length of MIDI message, in bytes. */
        unsigned char   data[3];
    };


    jack_client_t *getClient();

    void conectar(QString portaOrigem, QString clienteDestino, QString portaDestino) noexcept(false);



    void inicializarCliente(JackProcessCallback callback) noexcept(false);

    void addClientePorta(ClientePorta * cp);

    ClientePorta* getClientePorta(QString nomePorta);

    void sendMIDI(QString outputPortName, jack_nframes_t nframes ) noexcept(false);

private:
    QString clientName;
    QString inputPortName;
    QString outputPortName;
    QMap<QString,ClientePorta*> portas;
    jack_client_t   *jackClient = NULL;

};
```

The Cliente.cpp is:

```
#include "Cliente.h"
#include <QDebug>

Cliente::Cliente(QString clientName)
{
    this->clientName = clientName;
}

void Cliente::inicializarCliente(JackProcessCallback callback) noexcept(false){
    jackClient = jack_client_open(clientName.toUtf8().data(), JackNoStartServer, NULL);

    int err = jack_set_process_callback(jackClient, callback , this);
}
};
```

I'm ommiting the rest of the implementation since it is not relevant. I'm also not asking about lib jack. The focus is how to pass a C++ function as parameter to a C callback as show above.

Comment: 1) Why swearing in the function names? 2) What is `callbackMotherFucker`? 3) What are those "compilation problems" you experience? Do you get errors? What are those? 4) Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Is English your first language?  You do know that those names are expletives in English, right?  English not being your first language and just picking up words from movies maybe an excuse, but just barely.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but If I was really intend to offend somebody, I would not risk my low (but hard labored) reputation . I would just say what I have to say. And what I have to say is "I need help with a programming problem" that unfortunately leaked to the forum with a bad name. I think we all understand. Thanks to point me that. It was a mistake. I fixed. And I'll please ask you to think about consider the edit and remove the down vote. It is hard to ask hard things. It is not like "how to print a hello world concatenated with an integer?". Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormQStudio::theCallback` is not a function. It's a non-static member function, which means that it can only be called through an object of type `FormQStudio`, a pointer to which is passed as `this` to the function.

C doesn't know anything about C++ classes or class members. So it's not capable of calling such a function.

Moreover, the `&` operator applied to `FormQStudio::theCallback` produces a ["pointer-to-member-function"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) (PMF), which is not at all the same thing as a pointer to a function. (That's probably why you're seeing compiler errors, although it's hard to know exactly what you tried from the code sample in your question.) So even C++ programs couldn't use that as a stand-alone callback, although they could use the `.*`/`->*` syntax to invoke it with a provided class intance object reference/pointer.. (Note: these days it's better to use `std::invoke` rather than the rather obscure operators.)

If it turns out that `FormQStudio::theCallback` doesn't actually use `this` at all, then make it `static`. Then you can take its address and use that as a function pointer. (Although I think it's not guaranteed that C and C++ functions have the same calling conventions, so it's conceivable that you could still have problems passing it to a C function expecting a callback.)

Comment: Thank you very much, @rici for the clarification. I was not aware of that. It does compile well using static member function .

Comment: A C and a C++ compiler from the same vendor, targeting the same platform, will normally use the same calling convention for an "ordinary" (to use your description) function. So passing a static member function of a C++ class to C will work, if the types of arguments and return value make sense in both C and C++ (e.g. built-in types on C and C++, trivial C++ class types).   All bets are off, even between C compilers from different vendors, unless there is documented compatibility (which thankfully is common practice on a number of platforms, but is not guaranteed).

Comment: @peter if the platform abi specifies that c and c++ use the same calling convention, which I think is usual, then it should interop both between languages and between vendors. All I said is that it is not guaranteed, which I think is also your conclusion. If you have a specific edit in mind, I'm certainly open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the fact that the last parameter to `jack_set_process_callback`() is a `void *`, and it gets passed through to the callback function.

This is a common design pattern with C libraries to make them usable with C++.

What you are going to do is pass `this` of the object whose method you wish to invoke, as a callback, as the `void *` with the callback pointer to an `extern "C"` linkage wrapper function that takes the `void *`, then `reinterpret_cast`s it back to a class instance pointer, and then invokes its method, something like:

```
extern "C" {

int fwd_callback(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
    FormQStudio *p=reintrerpret_cast<FormQStudio *>(arg);

    return p->theCallback(nframes);
}

};

// ...

FormQStudio *some_object;

// ...

jack_set_process_callback(client, fwd_callback, reinterpret_cast<void *>(some_object));
```

Of course, it's on you to make sure that the `some_object` still exist and is a valid object, when the callback gets invoked.